# How to get a left border to run until the end of the page?

Tags: css, border

I would like to style my page so the content is in the middle and has a yellow border on the left, running from the top of the page to the bottom.

Currently I can only get it to go to the bottom using px, or using inherit making it stop until the end of my data. The following code didn't work.

```
.content{ min-height:100%;}
html{ height:100%;}
```

The complete code:

```
html
{
    font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    background-image:url('../Images/tile.jpeg');         
}

.content
{ 
    width:700px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:5px;    
    background-color:White;
}

.button
{
    font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
}
```

How can I get it to run to the bottom of the complete page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a forgotten div .. Added the div to the CSS with 100% height and BAM!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  For the benefit of the community please edit this answer to include the code for this solution

Answer (score 1):

- Use a background image for the page, with background positioning
- Research "full height css" and take a look at http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Comment: i tried that .. But it doesn't work. I am using a class, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tom, you'll have to provide a live example to move forward with this. Either your own host or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Right, don't assign a background to html, assign it to body, and look into background-positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position

Comment: Paste what you have in jsfiddle, please.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desired browser-support, you could always just add `min-height:100%;` to your content div.

If you don't mind using JavaScript, you could also add a simple snippet to set `height:100%;` if the height of the content container is less than the height of the window.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    if($('#content').height() < $(window).height())
    {
        $('#content').css('height','100%');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gBtTf/

Comment: I was going to -1 this because there's no `JQuery` or `Javascript` tag on the question, but this solution really does make sense. It will probably take less time to implement than making a background in Photoshop. My only complaint would be loading JQuery JUST for this. If the OP uses JQuery for other stuff, then yes, this solution is the best 'fix it and move on' idea.

Comment: @Tom what do you mean you tried it, and what did it do instead? Did you load JQuery? Did you wrap it in a dom ready function?

Comment: Oh I meant the min-height: 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS try this

```
<style type="text/css">
#blah{
    border-left-width:Xpx;
    border-left-color:#xxx;
    HERE add all the code for
    content
    }
</style>
```

where blah is the id of your div, paragraph tag, etc and you'd have to customize the width and color of course.

**EDIT** the css was edited, try this out, but instead of making a div for your border, add this to the content div, which should have a height of 100% or a min-height of 100%. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Classes too, but then you'd change the "#blah" to ".blah"

Comment: Your code says px, meaning it will only go 100pixels down. I guess you meant %, but that doesn't work.